# Preserving transparency in eps file

Tags: gimp, eps

I have an EPS file with transparency. How can I convert it to PNG with GIMP and preserve transparency?

Edit: I tried opening it in GIMP and exporting as PNG. Didn't work.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop could do the conversion easily - EPS would be loaded with transparency. Here's a simple EPS opened in Photoshop (no edits done):

[image]

I guess you are not going to use Photoshop nor other commercial stuff which could do the job.

There's an earlier answer which suggests converting the background to transparent with color to alpha in GIMP.  It's a good idea as long as the image doesn't contain white. Insert alpha channel with Layer > Transparency  if there's none.

Nearly white can be handled, for ex. those greys stay opaque if you adjust the treshold sliders properly:

[image]

If there's in the image much white that cannot be protected easily with a selection, color to alpha doesn't do the job. In this case the background removal can be tiresome.

As a fast workaround without installing anything try website Photopea https://www.photopea.com

It's a surprisingly well working Photoshop imitation for RGB images (it knows nothing of CMYK printing). Open your EPS there and export as PNG. Use option "Do not include palette" if you want your PNG as RGB image, not as indexed color image.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the background after loading using:

1. `Layers>Transparency>Add alpha channel`
2. `Colors>Color to alpha`